# Add values in new column of df based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df` sorted by `date` and the by `name` :

```
         date     name   valor 
  2  2018-03-01   ACC      75      
  0  2018-03-01   ACE      50     
  0  2018-03-20   ACE      50   
  1  2018-03-01   BBV      20    
  1  2018-03-14   BBV      20
  5  2018-04-16   BBV      58
  6  2018-04-20   BBV     -58
```

I am looking forward to generate a new `column` (called `result`)in the df where if one of the values in `name` is the same as the one after  , then add them together in the new column.

The desired output would look something like this:

```
     date        name    valor  result 
  2  2018-03-01   ACC      75     75
  0  2018-03-01   ACE      50     50
  0  2018-03-20   ACE      50    100 
  1  2018-03-01   BBV      20     20
  1  2018-03-14   BBV      20     40
  5  2018-04-16   BBV      58     98
  6  2018-04-20   BBV     -58     40
```

This is what I am trying:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(1,len(df)+1):
        if (row['name'][i]==row['name'][i+1]) and ( row['name'][i-1]!=row['name'][i]):
            df["result"]=df["valor"][i]+df["valor"][i+1]
        elif (row['name'][i]==row['name'][i+1]) and (row['name'][i-1]==row['name'][i]):
            df["result"]=df["result"][i]+df["valor"][i+1]
```

An `indexing error` outputs indicating `string index out of range`, however I am sure there should be a more efficient way to obtain the desired output.

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `groupby.cumsum` for this. Using vectorised functionality which comes  with `pandas` is usually more efficient and cleaner than iterating rows.

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('name')['valor'].cumsum()

print(df)

         date name  valor  result
2  2018-03-01  ACC     75      75
0  2018-03-01  ACE     50      50
0  2018-03-20  ACE     50     100
1  2018-03-01  BBV     20      20
1  2018-03-14  BBV     20      40
5  2018-04-16  BBV     58      98
6  2018-04-20  BBV    -58      40
```